# Bridge server for connecting two databases?

Tags: networking, database, sql, bridge

I'm in a bit of a pickle.

I currently have 2 database servers.
One is hosted in the US and is online on the internet.
The other is local, working only on LAN and external connections are not allowed.

Now, I have a web application that uses both servers. Currently the application was only local so we had no problem. But now, we are trying to move the application to the server in the US. Now, it can communicate with the database on that server, but it is unable to connect to the database that in local as it doesn't allow external connections (and for bureaucratic reasons, I can't allow public connections on it).

Is there any way I can make a middleman server, that gets information from the local server, and sends it to the server in the US. Basically syncing the whole database any chance it gets.

I looked at SymmetricDS but I'm not sure if this can be done with it.

Comment: Is this any particular database server?

Comment: Oracle and MySQL. If syncing between the two is not possible, both can be Oracle